# Bluetooth headphones not connecting/pairing on fedora

Tags: linux, fedora, bluetooth

Before anything am new to fedora so am sorry if i missed something obvious

So my Bluetooth headphones refuse to connect to the laptop am using a small usb bluetooth adapter the problem isn’t from the headphones as they connect to other devices without any problems

it refuses to pair/connect or do anything and just stays in an infinite loop of connecting until it times out while when trying to connect my phone with Bluetooth it connects first try and instantly I tried reinstalling the drivers and restarting it and even connecting from the terminal by bluetoothctl all not working and all lead to same problem even when it pairs it doesn’t connect just the word paired without it connecting then it instantly unpairs again

I have to add that i used to use pop-os and the headphones used to work normally with it on the same device with same usb bluetooth adapter

Comment: hm, maybe you need to repeat the pairing procedure? The headphones see your bluetooth adapter, think, hey, I know that adapter! They and I negotiated a key to communicate before! And expects that your Linux does in fact know that key – which might not be the case, since it's the same hardware, but not the same bluetooth software behind it with access to the same key :)